# How to invoke function of .cpp with button click event inside .h file?

Tags: c++, button, onclick

In my project there is one .cpp file which include main() function and one more function which I want to call from Form1.h on button click event.

**My code:**

My someting.cpp

```
main()
{

Application::Run(gcnew Form1());
return 0;
}

my_function()
{
 /code
}
```

My Form1.h

```
namespace somthing {
    //auto generated code

   private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e)
   {  
       my_function();   
   }
}
```

Comment: when i call function from buttonclick it shows Form1.h(136) : error C2065: 'my_function' : undeclared identifier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because the .h file doesn't know the content of the .cpp file.

Try declaring the body of your onClick in the .cpp file.

Comment: but button_click is not member of  .cpp? please help  I'm beginner to c++  :(

Comment: do I need to create new .cpp for function related to Form1.h and how to relate .cpp with .h?

Comment: button_click is a member, if you include Form1.h in the .cpp where the main is located.

Comment: included "Form1.h" still showing : error C2065: 'button_Click' : undeclared identifier

Comment: Wait, what are you trying to do? Are you defining a class in Form1.h? Can you plase show all code? Cause the private: code can only be used inside a class, as far as I know.